# How to loop through result set and get rows in equal split

Tags: java

I have a sql query, where I will get 10000 rows from it can you tell me any way that I can split that and use 500 rows each time do some operation and again next 500 rows and so on, can you suggest me which way is the best for it, also 500 rows should be separated by 'OR' in order to make use of them I will be using them in an solr query

Comment: you can use limit in your query

Answer (score 1):

Issue multiple queries, one for each batch of 500 rows. In your query, you can use `LIMIT offset, count` to limit how many rows are returned and the offset of the first row to return. The offset of the initial row is 0.

Comment: If possible, can you give an example query to do it, also can you let me know how to make each row seperated by 'OR' using result set or any other method

Comment: @user3291784 - See [the answer by asmalindi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22651137/535871) for an example query. I'm not sure what you mean by having each row separated by 'OR'. You would typically access the rows one at a time or retrieve an array of results, one element per row (depending on the API you're using).

Comment: If my result rows are some thing like good bad excellent, if these three are the results rows, I want them as "good OR bad OR excellent" I want like this to use in a solr query

Comment: @user3291784 - I think you'll have to assemble that string in Java by traversing the result set. I think the only way you could combine values like that from multiple rows of a result set in SQL is with a stored procedure. The logic would be pretty much the same for a stored procedure or for Java code.

Answer (score 1):

you can split sql rows like 1-500, 500-1000 , 1000-1500 ... like that 
you can use following sql query .

```
 SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT start, end
```

it will be like

```
 SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 500 
 SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 500, 1000
```

start end  values you have generate one your code

Answer (score 0):

You can get rows in equal split with use of Top keyword (**Sql server**)

```
Select top 500 * from tableName where id > lastId
```

For **MySql**

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT lastCount, 500
```

Comment: Unfortunately, OP has 10,000 rows, not 1,000.

Comment: ok so you want 500 in each next iteration? then i guess you need to keep track of number of iterations you have made..or id of last record you pulled.. so that you can modify this query using where clause

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the whole query and [process it 500 rows at a time](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28622) by calling setFetchSize(500) on your statement object. This is standard JDBC though your driver is not required to support it.